# Parse orQueryWithSubqueries not working correctly (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nosql

I'm working on implementing messaging functionality into my swift app, which runs on Parse, and querying for `Conversation` objects using the `orQueryWithSubqueries` method isn't working out like it should. Here is how I set up my query:

```
    var user1 = PFQuery.getUserObjectWithId("someUserObjectID")
    var user2 = PFQuery.getUserObjectWithId("otherUserObjectID")

    var query1 = PFQuery(className: "Conversation")
    query1.whereKey("user1", equalTo: user1!)
    query1.whereKey("user2", equalTo: user2!)
    var query2 = PFQuery(className: "Conversation")
    query2.whereKey("user1", equalTo: user2!)
    query1.whereKey("user2", equalTo: user1!)

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([query1, query2])
    query.includeKey("user1")
    query.includeKey("user2")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            println("Found conversation object!")
        } else {
            var errorCode = error!.code
            if (errorCode == 101) {
                println("Did not find conversation object!")
            } else {
                println("Unknown error occurred.")
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially, in my scheme a `Conversation` object is a `PFObject` with two relevant fields: `user1` and `user2`... which simply defines the two users that the conversation is between. The reason that I need this query to work is that when a user wants to start a new `Conversation` with a friend... I first check if that `Conversation` exists, and this query is how I do that. Because I don't know who started the `Conversation`, I need to  check for both users in both user fields (my app automatically fills the user1 field with whoever started the conversation).

Anyway, here's where the weird behavior is happening. I have a conversation object in the cloud where:

```
user1 = someUser
user2 = otherUser
```

If I run my query the way that it is typed above... the `Conversation` object is not found by the `orQueryWithSubqueries` (even though `query1` should find the `Conversation` object!). However, if I remove `query2` from the `orQueryWithSubqueries`, or even just comment out either `whereKey` constraint in `query2`... the `Conversation` object is found. This is weird because `query2` shouldn't even have anything to do with finding the `Conversation` object! Because `query1` is the one that matches the object, and `orQueryWithSubqueries` are supposed to return object that match either query. Can any one shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this issue, I never did find a way to get the `orQueryWithSubqueries` to work properly (may be a bug in the Parse iOS SDK), but this was my workaround:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Conversation")
    query.whereKey("user1", containedIn: [user1, user2])
    query.whereKey("user2", containedIn: [user1, user2])

    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {

        } else {
            var errorCode = error!.code
            if (errorCode == 101) {

            } else {
                // Handle error here.
            }
        }
    }
```